# Will a cylinder/sphere roll on a rope if half of it is surrounded by rope and one end of the rope being pulled?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, rotation

[Rolling a cylinder using a rope having one end fixed and another end mobile](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/667464/rolling-a-cylinder-using-a-rope-having-one-end-fixed-and-another-end-mobile/667517?noredirect=1#comment1496386_667517)

Will the cylinder/sphere roll as per the conditions mentioned in the above question(link)? Are there any additional conditions for that like infinite resistance(friction) or anything else?