# How does the tension exactly act on the pulley?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

Everyone says that $T_1$ and $T_2$ will act on the patch of pulley wrapped by the string. So do they act on arcs $AB$ and $CD$ respectively? If not, then how do they act?

And if $T_1 = T_2 = T$, they how do we know or calculate that resultant of $T_1$ and $T_2 = 2T$ vertically downwards? (since, it's just written everywhere that $R = 2T$ for keeping the pulley in equilibrium)
And how is the vector sum of all the forces on the patch directed vertically downward? (So that we have to pull the force vertically upward to keep the pulley in equilibrium?

I am not able to make a clear picture in my mind of how does exactly $T$ acts on the pulley?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE. "Do my work for me" questions aren't allowed here. Show what you tried, and if you have several questions, split them accordingly.

Comment: It's not any work, i am not asking any specific question, it's just a conceptual question. And i already wrote what i know about how the tension acts in the first line only. I supposedly can't make my own theory on "how tensions work". I am not Newton. I don't know what more do you want me to do in this question.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/713352/44126).

Comment: @rob Can you please tell how did you take the magnitude of resultant as Td θ ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question.  Tension is a force applied to the string, not the pulley.  However, a detailed evaluation shows that the pully does behave as if the tensions on the string were directly acting on the pully.  For a detailed discussion, see https://www.academia.edu/36857242/Force_and_torque_of_a_string_on_a_pulley_Force_and_torque_of_a_string_on_a_pulley

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have a mass on one side , so say T1=mg, to hold mg without the wheel you would have to apply a force T2=mg directly awards. the shell just changes the direction of the force, you could hold in any direction as long, as the string goes partly around the wheel.the force is on any point of the string on the wheel the same.  Finally you can draw downwards. Instead of you pulling, you could just put another mg on the right side. So the nail which holds the wheel has to support 2*mg+ the weight of the wheel, so R=T1+T2 is only correct if the wheel has no weight. also the friction on the wheel is neglected.